# SAP HANA PARTITIONED TABLE CALCULATION VIEW RUNNING SLOW IN COMPARISON TO NON-PARTITIONED TABLE CALCULATION VIEWE

Tags: hana

I have large size table , close to 1 GB and the size of this table is growing every week, it has total rows as 190 millions, I started getting alerts from HANA to partition this table, so I planned to partition this with column which is frequently used in Where clause.

My HANA System is scale out system with 8 nodes.

In order to compare the partition query performance difference with this un-partitioned table, I created calculation views on top of this un-partitioned table and recorded the query performance.

I partitioned this table using HASH method and by number of servers, and recorded the query performance. By this way I would have good data distribution across servers. I created calculation view and recorded query performance.

To my surprise I have found that my un-partitioned table calculation view query is performing better in comparison to partitioned table calculation view.

This was really shock. Not sure why non partitioned table Calculation view responding better to partitioned table Calculation view.

I have plan viz output files but not sure where to attach it.

Let me know why this is the behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is not a straight-forward question that can be answered correctly as such. 
What I can do though is to list some factors that likely will play a role here:

- a non-partitioned table needs a single access to the table structure while the partitioned version requires at least one access for each partition
- if the `SELECT` is not actually providing a `WHERE` condition that can be evaluated by the HASH function used for the partitioning, then **all** partitions always have to be evaluated and no partition pruning can take place.
- HASH partitioning does not take any additional knowledge about the data into account, which means that similar data does not get stored together. This has a negative impact on  data compression. Also, each partition requires its own set of value dictionaries for the columns where a single-partition/non-partitioned table only needs one dictionary per column.
- You mentioned that you are using a scale-out system. If the table partitions are distributed across the different nodes, then every query will result in cross-node network communication. That is an additional workload and waiting time that simply does not exist with non-partitioned tables.
- When joining partitioned tables each partition of the first table has to be joined with each partition of the second table, if no partition-wise join is possible.

There are other/more potential reasons for why a query against partitioned tables can be slower than against a non-partitioned table. All this is extensively explained in the [SAP HANA Administration Guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.03/en-US/66a1819e7eda4151ace6c02a72887fcd.html).

As a general guidance, tables should only be partitioned if that cannot be avoided and when the access pattern of queries are well understood. It is definitively not a feature that you just "switch on" and everything will just work fine.

Comment: Partitioning was a good method to seperate hot data from cold data and keep size of frequently used data of a table smaller. Additionally, the disk IO could be increased if data is on different disks by processing parallel reads. Maybe reading all table data might perform worse but with filters you may have better results